# Animate map to marker position in onClick method

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I found a strange bug in the googleMap v2. When I try to animateCamrea to a marker position inside of the override Marker onClick method it doesn't work. Only moveCamera seems to work in this scenario. Even when I try to animate camera to a random position it still doesn't work.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker mmarker) {

    if(mmarker.getSnippet().equals("CITY")){

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mmarker.getPosition(), (float) 11.20));
        //updateMapMarkers(0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour. Why are you re-defining it?

If you return `false` from `onMarkerClick`, the Maps API will perform its default behaviour (panning to the marker).

You'll want to return `true` if you are overriding that behaviour or don't want it to happen.

Check the [documentation for `OnMarkerClickListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) for more information.

If you only want to animate on a condition like that, then this will be more succinct:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker mmarker) {
    return !mmarker.getSnippet().equals("CITY");
}
```

This will pan the map only when the snippet is "CITY". You may also want to reverse the call to `equals()`.

Comment: It worked when I returned mmarker.getSnippet().equals("CITY");